# Dynamically add page in viewPager without lose focus

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

my problem is that I have a vertical viewPager and on my pages I have a register, I want to add a new page to the pager when the textField is being filled, but when I add a new page and call the notifyDataChanged () I lose my focus in the text field. There is a way to do this without losing focus?

To add a new page in the viewPager I am adding the new content in my List and calling this method in the pageAdapter:

```
public void updateArrayDemoData(List<RegisterPageControl> newArrayData){
        this.arrayDemoData = newArrayData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


@Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hold the index of the current pager selected each and every time in a variable like int indexNumber. after updating list call

```
pager.setCurrentItem(indexNumber);
```